# How to skip serde serialization with skip_serializing_if for a boolean field

Tags: rust, serde

I would like to skip field serialization if the value is `false`.

In JSON, this would serialize `Foo` as either `{bar: true}` or `{}`.

```rust
#[derive(Serialize)]
pub struct Foo {
    // This does not compile - bool::is_false does not exist
    #[serde(skip_serializing_if = "bool::is_false")]
    pub bar: bool,
}
```

Comment: Define a function `bar_is_false` yourself and use that in `skip_serializing_if`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, according to the serde docs:

> `#[serde(skip_serializing_if = "path")]`
> Call a function to determine whether to skip serializing this field. The given function must be callable as `fn(&T) -> bool`, although it may be generic over `T`

So you can either define such a function yourself

```
fn is_false(b: &bool) -> bool { !b }
```

Or you could look for such a function in the standard library.

- For skipping true: `Clone::clone`
- For skipping false: `std::ops::Not::not` ([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=140892d51573b9a9368c895c1cddef7f))
  Note that `bool::not` won't work because you need the `Not` impl on
  `&bool`: `<&bool as std::ops::Not>::not`

Comment: Thank god for `std::ops::Not::not`. Having to define `is_false` hurts my soul.

Answer (score 3):

To only skip serializing when the boolean value false you should define a function that returns true when you want to skip serialization like this:

```rust
fn is_false(b: &bool) -> bool {
    *b == false
}
```

and then annotate the struct like so `#[serde(skip_serializing_if = "is_false")]`.

Here is a full sample and [playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b452fb231a1d8a11fb867872615d6701):

```rust
use serde::Serialize;

#[derive(Serialize)]
pub struct Foo {
    #[serde(skip_serializing_if = "is_false")]
    pub bar: bool,
}

fn main() {
    let test1 = Foo { bar: true };
    let test2 = Foo { bar: false };

    println!("{}", serde_json::to_string(&test1).unwrap());
    println!("{}", serde_json::to_string(&test2).unwrap());
}

fn is_false(b: &bool) -> bool {
    *b == false
}
```

You can also skip serializing default values in general like this:

```rust
use serde::Serialize;

#[derive(Serialize)]
pub struct Foo {
    #[serde(default, skip_serializing_if = "is_default")]
    pub bar: bool,
}

fn main() {
    let test1 = Foo { bar: true };
    let test2 = Foo { bar: false };

    println!("{}", serde_json::to_string(&test1).unwrap());
    println!("{}", serde_json::to_string(&test2).unwrap());
}

fn is_default<T: Default + PartialEq>(t: &T) -> bool {
    t == &T::default()
}
```

and here is the corresponding [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=654248b8fad0db19933fec7ad45d3d4a).

Answer (score 1):

The simplest answer is to use the output of the `Not::not` function, which is already implemented for `&bool`.

```rust
use std::ops::Not;

#[derive(Serialize)]
pub struct Foo {
    #[serde(skip_serializing_if = "<&bool>::not")]
    pub bar: bool,
}
```

Comment: The top answer already mentions that.

Comment: Mmh, In all fairness, I only mention the longer `<&bool as std::ops::Not>::not`. It's the same thing of course, but if you're looking to copy and paste code from SO, this is neater.